# Не получается передать массив в view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте.

Контроллер Welcome:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('users_view');
}

function users()
{
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_users();
    $this->load->view('users_view', $data);
}
```

Модель:

```
<?php
class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_users()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('users'); 
        return $query->result_array(); 
    }
}
?>
```

сам View:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>тест</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (is_array($users)) 
{
    foreach($users as $item)
    {
        echo $item['id'];
        echo $item['login'];
        echo $item['name'];
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

выдает ошибку " Undefined variable: users"

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вынес всё из функции users в index, всё выводится, но при этом окно ошибки остается.

Answer (score 1):

Откуда взялись $users в шаблоне? Скорее всего они в $data, которая вроде бы передается в рендер. В $data['users']